# Auto Increment ID Excel VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, auto-increment

I want to Auto Increment the ID when I insert new data into the excel and this is my code

When I use this code it does auto increment but when the excel sheet doesn't have any ID input yet it doesn't work

```
Try
        cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\Users\\Barbatos\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx " + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        cn.Open()
        cm = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX([ID]) FROM [Sheet1$]", cn)

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read = True Then
            Me.IDEm.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cn.Close()
```

But when I use this code It does Auto increment even the excel sheet doesn't have any ID input yet but It only increment by 10 and its stops at 10

```
Try
        cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\Users\\Barbatos\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx " + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        cn.Open()
        cm = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX([ID]) AS MAXIMUM FROM [Sheet1$]", cn)

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read = True Then
            If IsDBNull(dr("MAXIMUM")) Then
                Me.IDEm.Text = 1
            Else
                Me.IDEm.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: So debug your code.  Set a breakpoint and step through the code to see exactly what the state is at each step and exactly when and how that state differs from your expectations.

Comment: Also, why are you still using a data reader when you have accepted my answer to your other question that calls `ExecuteScalar`?

Comment: It's only increment by 10 and i think it is already working Sorry

Comment: You're not making sense.  It doesn't increment by 10.  It increments by 1.  If you're saying that it only increments TO 10 then that's another matter but, if that is the case then you need to debug your code and not expect us to magic a solution.  Debug the code and, if you still can't figure out exactly what's wrong, at least you can describe to us exactly how the behaviour of the code differs from what you expect.